# Involvement of S3 storage with JDBC queries

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In our company we are working with the Snowflake-JBDC-Driver. Playing around a little bit, we noticed that not the full amount of results came back when executing a query with a large result set. Only after adding another Firewall-rule to access S3 storage were we able to retrieve all the records of a query.

I was then looking into the source code of the JDBC-Driver and there indeed I found code, that seems to communicate with S3, but it seems to me, that this feature has to be used explicitly and is not something that is done behind the scenes.

So my question: Does the Snowflake-JDBC-Driver work with S3 buckets when dealing with large queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake caches all large result sets on the internal stage of the Snowflake Account. For AWS this would be an S3 bucket indeed.

All drivers (this includes JDBC as well) do retrieve the large result sets from the internal stage automatically and this is not something that needs to be configured explicitly. Actually you cannot configure the behavior.

More information also available [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue we have is regarding the additional firewall rule we have to setup for S3. As I understand from your provided link, this feature can be deactivated by setting 'USE_CACHED_RESULT' to false? And could you add a code point in the Snowflake JDBC driver where the call to S3 is made?

Comment: It cannot be deactivated using `USE_CACHED_RESULT=false`. The use of that parameter only indicates that every time you run the query don't use the cache if already done before, but the results will be stored on the internal stage anyway if they are over a certain size. Like I mentioned this is done automatically and cannot be deactivated (it is done for performance reasons).

Comment: Ok. But does the driver in that case retrieve the result from S3 directly or will it be coming from the database endpoint? I'm asking because in one case we only need to open the firewall for accessing the snowflake database and in the other scenario we would need to open the firewall to snowflake database AND S3 storage.

Comment: You should have access opened to both Snowflake endpoint and the S3 storage endpoint as well at all time. You can verify what URLs need to be whitelisted at firewall using [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd) or the output of function [SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/system_allowlist)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. So that means the driver is directly communicating with an S3 storage in that case. I know about the SYSTEM$ALLOWLIST. I just couldn't find the point in the code nor in the logs, where the connection to S3 is established.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For JDBC look for the [SnowflakeS3Client](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/cloud/storage/SnowflakeS3Client.java) class.

Comment: I was finally able to debug the code: It's not the SnowflakeS3Client involved in this scenario, but the SnowflakeChunkDownloader. Depending on the url's, this downloader downloads the chunks from an S3 bucket.